# How can I diff 2 files while ignoring differences in hexadecimal values within?

Tags: bash, shell, diff, zsh

I have 2 files, they are different versions of the same thing. However, one has different hexadecimal values, memory addresses, than the other.

Is there a diff command or a filter I can use to diff with so that the output will only be lines that are different after ignoring different hex values?

`# diff output I would like to filter:
-    .. 0x000000010e428bb4 _swift_stdlib_bridgeErrorToNSError + 388",
-    .. 0x000000010e3f0347 swift_dynamicCast + 2455",
-    .. 0x000000010e3f051a swift_dynamicCast + 2922",
+    .. 0x00000001013f2bb4 _swift_stdlib_bridgeErrorToNSError + 388",
+    .. 0x00000001013ba347 swift_dynamicCast + 2455",
+    .. 0x00000001013ba51a swift_dynamicCast + 2922",`

Comment: What about an `awk` to filter out the words that look like hex then pipeline to `diff`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `sed` to rewrite the hex numbers. Something like:

```
sed 's/0x[0-9a-f]*/HEX/g'
```

Which given input like:

```
.. 0x000000010e428bb4 _swift_stdlib_bridgeErrorToNSError + 388",
```

Results in:

```
.. HEX _swift_stdlib_bridgeErrorToNSError + 388",
```

You could combine this with your `diff` statement like (assuming `bash`):

```
diff <(sed 's/0x[0-9a-f]*/HEX/g' file1) <(sed 's/0x[0-9a-f]*/HEX/g' file2)
```